# Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxPost is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, sts

i am getting this error in my console whick running ajax method

this is my ajax class'

```
$(document).ready(

    function() {
    
     $("#dndform").submit(function(event) 
         {
         
         event.preventDefault();
                ajaxPost();
    });
    

function ajaxPost() {
    var x = document.getElementById("monumber").value;
    console.log("url:" + "http://localhost:8080/dnd?monumber=" + x);


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/dnd?monumber=" + x,

        success: function(result) {
        if (result.status == "success") {
                                $("#postResultDiv")
                                    .html(
                                        "<p style='background-color:#7FA7B0; color:white; padding:20px 20px 20px 20px'>"
                                        + "Post Successfully! <br>"
                                        + "---> Congrats !!"
                                        + result.object.name
                                        + "</p>");
                            } else {
                                $("#postResultDiv").html(
                                    "<strong>Error</strong>");
                            }
                            console.log(result);
                        },
                        error: function(e) {
                            alert("Error!")
                            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            
        }
    });

}
});
```

this is my view class

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" />

<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dnd.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="/image/logo.jpg" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
    </div>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            </a> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Robi</a>


            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto text-uppercase">

                    <li class="nav-item"><a th:href="@{/home}"
                        class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a
                        class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"
                        role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Charging </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Calling Details</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Charging Details</a></li>
                            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/freeminutes}">Free
                                    Minutes</a></li>
                        </ul></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a th:href="@{/userdetails}"
                        class="nav-link" href="#">User Detail</a></li>


                    <li class="nav-item"><a th:href="@{/sms}" class="nav-link"
                        href="#">SMS Send</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/dnd}"
                        href="#">DND</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a th:href="@{/blockunblock}"
                        class="nav-link" href="#">Block/Unblock</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a th:href="@{/activate}"
                        class="nav-link" href="#">Activate</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a th:href="@{/deactivate}"
                        class="nav-link" href="#">Deactivate</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a
                        class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"
                        role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            MIS </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Date Wise</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Monthly</a></li>
                            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>

                        </ul></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a th:href="@{/logout}" class="nav-link"
                        href="#">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <form id="dndform" action="" th:action="@{/dnd}" method="get">

        <!-- number -->

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="number_field" class="form-label"> Enter ANI </label> <input
                name="monumber" type="tel" class="form-control" id="monumber"
                aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Here" />

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7" style="margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px">
            <button type="button" onclick="ajaxPost()" class="btn btn-primary">Check</button>
            <div id="getResultDiv" style="padding: 20px 10px 20px 50px">
                <ul class="list-group">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script th:src="@{/js/script.js}"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>
</html>
```

i am net with ajax i am still learning but when i hit save button i get this error
i think my ajax good is good but then why i am getting this error.

Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxPost is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (dnd:107)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing on **button** click and it not submitting the form

on form submit the **button** type must be `submit`

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    function ajaxPostRequest() {
        var x = document.getElementById("monumber").value;
        console.log("url:" + "http://localhost:8080/dnd?monumber=" + x);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/dnd?monumber=" + x,
            success: function(result) {
            if (result.status == "success") {
                                    $("#postResultDiv")
                                        .html(
                                            "<p style='background-color:#7FA7B0; color:white; padding:20px 20px 20px 20px'>"
                                            + "Post Successfully! <br>"
                                            + "---> Congrats !!"
                                            + result.object.name
                                            + "</p>");
                                } else {
                                    $("#postResultDiv").html(
                                        "<strong>Error</strong>");
                                }
                                console.log(result);
                            },
                            error: function(e) {
                                alert("Error!")
                                console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            }
        });
    }
     $("#dndform").submit(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         ajaxPostRequest();
    });
    


});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" />

<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dnd.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="/image/logo.jpg" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
    </div>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            </a> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Robi</a>


            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto text-uppercase">

                    <li class="nav-item"><a th:href="@{/home}"
                        class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a
                        class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"
                        role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Charging </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Calling Details</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Charging Details</a></li>
                            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/freeminutes}">Free
                                    Minutes</a></li>
                        </ul></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a th:href="@{/userdetails}"
                        class="nav-link" href="#">User Detail</a></li>


                    <li class="nav-item"><a th:href="@{/sms}" class="nav-link"
                        href="#">SMS Send</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/dnd}"
                        href="#">DND</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a th:href="@{/blockunblock}"
                        class="nav-link" href="#">Block/Unblock</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a th:href="@{/activate}"
                        class="nav-link" href="#">Activate</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a th:href="@{/deactivate}"
                        class="nav-link" href="#">Deactivate</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a
                        class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"
                        role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            MIS </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Date Wise</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Monthly</a></li>
                            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>

                        </ul></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a th:href="@{/logout}" class="nav-link"
                        href="#">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <form id="dndform" action="" th:action="@{/dnd}" method="get">

        <!-- number -->

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="number_field" class="form-label"> Enter ANI </label> <input
                name="monumber" type="tel" class="form-control" id="monumber"
                aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Here" />

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7" style="margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px">
            <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Check</button>
            <div id="getResultDiv" style="padding: 20px 10px 20px 50px">
                <ul class="list-group">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script th:src="@{/js/script.js}"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good solution, but remember that we should also explain why this fixes the issue in order to educate the OP and any future visitors.